# |z|=Re(z)-|Im(z)| how to solve the equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I realize that,  $Re(z)=x≥0$ and $Im(z)=y=0$
So I use $|z|=\sqrt(x^2+y^2),\text {   } z=x+iy$

then

$\sqrt(x^2+y^2)=x-|y|$

and you diffrentiate $y\ge0$ or $ y\lt0$

then if $y\ge0$

$\sqrt(x^2+y^2)=x-y$

if $ y\lt0\text{ }$
 We have to say that
$\sqrt(x^2+y^2)=x+y$

But how do I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=x-|y|$$ squaring we get
$$x^2+y^2=x^2+y^2-2x|y|$$ and we obtain $$0=-2x|y|$$ can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wasn't sure, if it is an equvalent transformation to square in this case. But i guess you can leave y in this form.